# Could not log into mysql server

Tags: mysql, linux

When I login without specifying host name, I could not login

`mysql -u root -p`

It displays the message

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

But if I use hostname, I am able to login

`mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root -p`

It didn't allow, even if I use localhost as my hostname

What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

I would check that mysql is started

```
service mysqld start
```

Comment: mysql is running. I am able to login with 127.0.0.1 as the host.

Comment: ok I had that same problem where I could login with 127.0.0.1 but not local host and it was because the service wasn't started. sorry I couldn't be of more assistance.